# Как уменьuить изображения и отступы в jQuery Carousel Evolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, изображения, carousel

Есть карусель-гармошка [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/9nkdn9ap/4/), построенная на базе [jQuery - Carousel Evolution](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Coverflow-Style-Image-Carousel-Plugin-For-jQuery-Carousel-Evolution.html).

Размеры фронтальной картинки можно задавать, а теневые под нее подстраиваются.

Вопрос: как задать определенные размеры и отступы теневых картинок (мне нужно их уменьшить и сместить больше за фронтальную) и убрать горизонтальный скролл?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        carouselWidth: 930,
        carouselHeight: 330,
        frontWidth: 350,
                frontHeight: 250,
        directionNav: true,
        shadow: true,
        buttonNav: 'bullets'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hMargin: 0.8,` - отступы по ширине (0,4 дефолт)

`vMargin: 0.4,` - отступы по высоте (0,2 дефолт)

```
    (document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        carouselWidth: 930,
        carouselHeight: 330,
        frontWidth: 350,
                frontHeight: 250,
        directionNav: true,
        shadow: true,
        hMargin: 0.8,
        vMargin: 0.4,
        buttonNav: 'bullets'
    });
});
```

Comment: Для эксперимента можно сделать значения *hMargin: 0.1,
        vMargin: 0.1*

Comment: @Kosmos я их как примеры задал, из песочницы

Comment: @Павел Игоревич а в каких величинах они измеряются?